# grouped barplot in R showing % of total in a category as height, color as factor and each group as a column of data

Tags: r, plot

I have the following data:

```
Category,72,78,79,99,102,123,132,175,249,258,290,291,295,312
P,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
P,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,0,1,1,0
P,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,3,2,0,0,1,1,0
P,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
P,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1
P,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
P,1,1,2,0,0,1,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,1
P,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
P,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,2,1,0,1
P,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
P,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
P,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Each sample is classified as either "P" or "NP".  I need to make a grouped barplot that shows the height of each bar as sum within category/sample count within category.  For example the first bar would be labeled "72" on the X-axis, and would have two bars side by side (and different color), one showing (7/12)*100 as its height and the second in a different color showing (0/11)*100 as its height.  I know this is likely pretty easy but all of the examples I can find do not group by column and do not calculate %.

The below image shows what I am looking for.  This is a really simplified dataset.  My actual data is far more complex.  The data above is stored in dataframe called "informdata."

[image]

Comment: Can you draw a simple graph representing your desired output? Otherwise it's vague what exactly you want.

Comment: Yes.  I added an image that shows what I am looking to replicate.  The image was easily produced in Excel but it does not seem quite as easy in R.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
d %>%
    gather(var, val, -Category) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = factor(var, sort(unique(as.numeric(var)))),
               y = val,
               fill = Category)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = function(a) 100*sum(a)/length(a),
             position = position_dodge())
```